# Is it possible to print the same timestamp as NSLog small within a macro?

Tags: objective-c, nslog, ctime

I want to make a custom `NSLog()` that logs to a file and I want to ship with it. NSLog also prints to the system log. I don't want that on the users machine. So I have to roll my own. Thats fine but: Exceptions (which get logged to a different file) print their timestamp info local time. To be able to insert them into the log I need the same timestamp. How?

`[NSDate date]` just returns GMT. `ctime()` needs a time_t struct. for that I would have to include time.h in every file I want to use the log. Any ideas?

Thanks

**Edit**: found it:

```
[[NSDate  date] descriptionWithCalendarFormat:@"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%F" timeZone:nil 
                        locale:[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation]]  UTF8String]
```

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong with using ctime here? It has what you need http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/ctime/localtime/.

Comment: this includes time_t in my macro. that means I have to include time.h everywhere where I want to log

Comment: Yes, maybe i will use it in a future project. But I just needed a quick (small) solution. I hate adding yet another framework...